# How to specify something other than pk or slug for DetailView

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-1.3

I was wondering if it was possible to use something besides a pk or slug when you are using a DetailView in Django 1.3.

For example, I currently have:

```
url(r'^mymodel/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', MyDetailView.as_view())
```

as my url. Say I wanted something like:

```
url(r'^mymodel/(?P<name>\d+)/$', MyDetailView.as_view())
```

where name would be a field in the model. Is there anyway to have the DetailView use that to 'grab' the object I want and pass it on to my template?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A slug doesn't have any particular significance in Django. It's just a name for a field that identifies a row. If your slug is called something else, eg `name`, just specify `name` as the `slug_field` attribute in your view subclass.

If you need something more complicated, you can always override `get_object` in the view class.

Comment: Overriding is all I needed to do here. Thanks!

Comment: also note that your url line must look like: url(r'^mymodel/(?P<slug>\d+)/$', MyDetailView.as_view())

Comment: You can set `slug_url_kwarg` in addition to `slug_field` so that your named parameter is not "slug" as user mpaf suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute "pk_url_kwarg"

> **urls.py**

```
url(r'^mymodel/(?P<name>\d+)/$', MyDetailView.as_view())
```

> **views.py**

```
class CustomDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = ModelName
    pk_url_kwarg = "name" # primary key(to identify object uniquely)
    template_name = "template.html"
```

#### Reference: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.1/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/