# Name 'Customer' is not defined CBV ListView

Tags: python, django

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from system import views

app_name = 'project'

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^cust/([\w-]+)/$',views.PublisherBookList.as_view()),
    ...
]
```

views.py

```
from . import models

class PublisherBookList(ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.name = get_object_or_404(Customer, name=self.args[0])
        return Customer.objects.filter(name=self.name)
```

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I do visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/custo/customername/

got error `name 'Customer' is not defined`

whats i missed here?...

Comment: Did you import customer model?

Comment: yes already did, `from . import models`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import Customer in your views.py

```
from .models import Customer
```

Comment: already did, i have lot of model. just error on views with `def get_queryset(self):` part.

Comment: You imported the module, but not the class. You can either change the import to `from .models import Customer` or use `models.Customer` everywhere instead of just `Customer`

Comment: ah gotcha. forgot do `models.` its work now, but nothing result. i check my db name `John`, put John on url and its show nothing.

Comment: By default Django detail view uses `pk` url kwarg, which is Django database ID of the object. If you want to use custom slug attr you need to add few things. Here's relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815655/django-using-slug-field-for-detail-url

Comment: Here it is explained how to alter default slug field https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780803/how-to-specify-something-other-than-pk-or-slug-for-detailview/